# Connection String of MS Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, database-connection

I have developed a Windows application in C#, and its database is in Access 2010.

I have the database connection string, but it gives an error:
***OleDbException Was Unhandled***

Please suggest me what is the problem & its solution.

```
con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="\\dtinaurdsna02\\LE-IN\\Admin\Quality Rating\\Quality_Rating_Tool\\Quality_Rating_Tool.accdb";Persist Security Info=True;");
```

Comment: what error r u getting

Comment: @shweta can you share your error so can rectify issue and give solution

Comment: Error is OleDbException Was Unhandled

Comment: above path is not valid path

Comment: @Swetha if path is not valid specify the apt path. is this database is with in your project folder?

Comment: So you ask us what the correct path on your machine is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know the path exactly you can use

```
con = new OleDbConnection
       (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source
             =\dtinaurdsna02\LE-IN\Admin\Quality
                Rating\Quality_Rating_Tool\Quality_Rating_Tool.accdb;
                Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxx;
                 Persist Security Info=True;");
```

If database is within the app folder and you can use below

```
string path = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
      path = path + "\\Quality_Rating_Tool.accdb;";
   con = new OleDbConnection
           (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source" + path);
```

Comment: I have use con = new OleDbConnection
       (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source
             =\dtinaurdsna02\LE-IN\Admin\Quality
                Rating\Quality_Rating_Tool\Quality_Rating_Tool.accdb;
                 Persist Security Info=True;"); connetion string & it is given error that not valid password

Comment: @Shweta i modified the connection string with how to add password.if you know the password for your database replace it there and try

Answer (score 1):

1) `\\` is an escaped `\`

2) You end your string after `Source=` because of the quotation mark. You might use ' instead of ".

3) `@` disables escaping

You need to read something about [Escaping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/h21280bw.aspx)!

```
con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource='\\dtinaurdsna02\\\LE-IN\\Admin\Quality Rating\\Quality_Rating_Tool\\Quality_Rating_Tool.accdb';Persist SecurityInfo=True;");
```

Answer (score 1):

> *var connect = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source= C:\Users\User1\Desktop\test.mdb";*
>
> *using(var conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
> {
> codes here
> }*

use like this

Answer (score 0):

Your "Data Source="\dtinaurdsna02\LE-IN\Admin\Quality Rating\Quality_Rating_Tool\Quality_Rating_Tool.accdb" is in Inverted commas eg.("")which is canceling out the original inverted commas... change it to this

```
con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='\\dtinaurdsna02\\LE-IN\\Admin\Quality Rating\\Quality_Rating_Tool\\Quality_Rating_Tool.accdb';Persist Security Info=True;");
```